# Virtualbox: getting guest to capture certain key presses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard, centos-7

I am using Ubuntu as host system, and CentOS7 as guest system, how, can I send for example certain keypresses or keypresses combination like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but to switch between terminal session in guest system, or in CentOS7 in my case, not in host system, or in my Ubuntu workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Preferences > Input` and click the `Host key`, then press the desired key combination to switch to host machine.

The best option is install guest addition and you need not use any key, it will behave like any other window on host. If it is a Windows host, the guest addition software is present in `VboxGuestAddition.iso` which is located at install directory (roughly `Program files/oracle/virtualBox/VboxGuestAddition.iso`).